# Home-made joint for a top window

Tags: windows, leak, winter, joints

I have some sort of artisanal, metal, top oriented, window that essentially serves as a light well (but the room is almost completey dark, the main door is covered by a curtain because my girl friend don't like the fact she can be seen from people outside, even if the door isn't connected directly to a street).

This window, which occasionaly leaks water when it rains a lot, is just plainly put down on this metal architecture, which is rusted despite its paint.

Apparently, before we moved in the apartment something like 8 months ago, somebody seems to have removed the joint, which would been quite big or flexible.

What kind of joint do I have to buy, or is there some way I could craft one (I know I can't possibly craft one, but I can still do something now before I buy it).

Here is the window:

[image: window]

[image: window]

[image: window]

Answer (score 2):

If you're refering to the sort of caulk-like stuff that runs along the edge of the glass, it's called 'window glazing putty', sometimes 'window glazing compound'.

You can find sites online that cover how to re-glaze a window; you may want to remove the glazing from the rest of the window so you can get a clean edge all the way around, and a matching color:

- http://www.hereandthere.org/oldhouse/windows-glazing-steps.html (has pictures)
- http://www.naturalhandyman.com/iip/infwindows/infgla.html (also covers removing old glazing)